# Get variable from data structure in highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to pass an ID to the data structure so that on click event I can use it to open a new tab in the browser. I supposed, wrongly, that I can use this.id like I can user this.color or this.name.
My structure data is like that:

```
var _DATA_XY0 =[{"id":24356,"name":"Title name","data":[[1322175600000,0.0],[1322780400000,8.301021537820063],[1323385200000,6.064466537188018],[1323990000000,2.580595528139673],[1324594800000,4.171990586412377],[1325199600000,3.0967211543766027],.......
```

I have this code to draw a XY chart:

```
Highcharts.stockChart(div, {
    exporting: {
        enabled: false,
        allowHTML: true
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    yAxis: {
        opposite: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
            }
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 2,
            color: 'silver'
        }]
    },

    plotOptions: {

        series: {
            showInNavigator: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        var win = window.open('https://localhost/' + this.id, '_blank');
                        if (win) {
                            win.focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b>',
        valueDecimals: 2,
        split: false
    },

    series: data
});
```

On the click event I use this:

```
var win = window.open('https://localhost/' + this.id, '_blank');
```

But this.id seems not to work. I use the same logic with scatter and it works.

thanks

Comment: what context are you running under? Do a `console.log(this)` to see what the current context is.

Comment: thanks @Nope checking in the context I see where the id is stored:   console.log(this.series.options.id);

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a different approach in events cause i need a lot more meta-data than the id. Maybe my approach provides you with the desired results.

I create the following object :

```
var graphEvents = {
  type: 'flags' , 
  data: new Array() , 
  onSeries: 'DataSet',
  events: {
    click : function(e){
      if(e.point.evt) {
        var myEvt = e.point.evt;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then push into the Data array of the Event Object the following :

```
graphEvents.data.push({
    x: Date.parse(myDate),
    title: "EventTitle" , 
    evt : {
      custom_key_a : value["a"] , 
      custom_key_b : value["b"] , 
      custom_key_c : value["c"] , 
      custom_key_d : value["d"] 
    }
});
```

Notice the "evt" key. This is a custom key i add to the Object , so that is available when the user clicks on it along with all the custom key:values i have inside it. That way when a User clicks on the Event , i can get all the Objects Meta from the code seen in the 1st Object:

```
events: {
  click : function(e){
    if(e.point.evt) {
      var myEvt = e.point.evt;
    }
  }
}
```

And now in the myEvt variable i have all and everything i need.